# How get latitude and longitude by client ip?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

i use this function to get client IP it work

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress; 
}

$ip = get_client_ip();
```

but how i can get latitude and longitude by sever side and not client side ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576423/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-a-users-latitude-and-longitude-from-an-ip-addres

Comment: The question you linked to isn't the same as this. This question is asking how to geolocate by IP server side, not client side.

Answer (score 6):

PHP does not have the in-built support for that. You could make use of third party libraries like [`ip2location`](http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db5-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude) to grab the longitude and latitude from the ip address.

**Sidenote** : Determining the latitude - longitude through an IP Address may not fetch you accurate information.

#### Uses [geoplugin.net](http://www.geoplugin.com/quickstart). See if this suits you.

```
<?php
$new_arr[]= unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
echo "Latitude:".$new_arr[0]['geoplugin_latitude']." and Longitude:".$new_arr[0]['geoplugin_longitude'];
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Latitude:180.240601 and Longitude:12.9819
```

Comment: is it opensource huh ?

Comment: Nope it is not. You need to purchase it.

Comment: Nothing as I know of mate.

Comment: See my answer I am using it. And is opensource.

Comment: @Echo where ?? provide link please

Comment: See my answer also with link http://in1.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: @Echo, However , that is not shipped with PHP , Its an extension anyway that is what my point is.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I have shared what I have in my knowledge. :)

Comment: i dont understand how it help me?

Comment: @user3405726, See if that example suits you.

Answer (score 4):

Best option from php.net which is also open source: [Geo IP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)

You can install it using following steps. Which are given on the link I have provided:

Run these commands in terminal.

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat

sudo apt-get install php5-geoip
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks can you Expand?

Comment: FOllow the tutorial. You need to install geoIP first using terminal

Comment: i checked there but i dont see there the function that give me latitude by ip that i get from my function on Top of page

Comment: It can give latitude lingitude by IP & Website address both. I am using it.

Comment: Just use print_r(geoip_record_by_name('111.118.212.180')); or print_r(geoip_record_by_name('google.com'));  after installing you will get to know.

Comment: I tried to do this with python flask and the results didn't work. Since I was testing locally I guess it tried to use `127.0.0.1` as the IP

Answer (score 2):

For a quick, copy-and-paste solution, I have written code for accomplishing this task.

I use this function:

```
    function getUserIP()
    {
        $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $client;
        }
        elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $forward;
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = $remote;
        }

        return $ip;
    }

    $ipAddr = getUserIP();

    $geoIP  = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/$ipAddr"), true);

    echo 'lat: ' . $geoIP['latitude'] . '<br />';
    echo 'long: ' . $geoIP['longitude'];
```

Outputs:

```
34.0731
118.3994
```

It uses the (free) [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net) API which I have found to be extremely fast with a comprehensive database. Being free, it has a limit of 10000 requests per hour (just under 3 per second), which should suffice for most projects' needs.

Comment: this method is not Accurate

Comment: with this method i get latitude 31.5 but when i check in google map i get 32.564102 something like this

Comment: @user3405726, Can you give the IP Address ?

Comment: ip address 5.29.204.156

Comment: this will be the nearest registered point in the database. it is accurate for _free_ software. if you want the _exact_ location, you will need to use GPS (not free) which does not rely on IP addresses. this is about as accurate you are going to get for IP addresses, which was your original request.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider getting the exact location of the user from client side using Javascript API [`navigator.geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorGeolocation.geolocation). The advantage of using this is, it will be accurate.

The issue with IP to Geo is that, there is no guarantee that the info will be accurate. It depends on how updated the data is.

On the other hand, the javascript API directly takes the geo based on GPS or Network address (whichever is accurate). But the user will have to give permission to access to his GPS.

You can use the Javascript (if user gives permission) or fall back to ip to geo conversion

**How to Use**

```
 if (navigator.geolocation && navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          // save location by sending to server
      }, function() { alert("Couldn't get your position!"); });
 }
```

Comment: thanks but it have to be in server side because i filter in data base

Comment: thanks worked for me too !!!!